# Что делать с переменной?

Tags: сессия, memcached, php

Добрый день.

Есть класс, который дергает из базы значение, обрабатывает его несложными математическими операциями и, собственно, отдает числовое значение, например, 145.

Данное значение выводится на всех страницах системы. Что лучше в плане оптимизации (нагрузка) при первоначальном расчете значения: записать его в переменную сессии и вызывать саму переменную при генерировании страницы либо вызывать метод класса, который возвращает эту переменную.

P.S. Понятно дело, что лучше кэшировать это все дело, но этот вариант не рассматривается. 
P.P.S. Записывать один раз в куку, а потом дергать JS, тоже не интересует.

Comment: @barseon, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы записал в сессию, она в принципе и предназначена для хранения "статичных" данных о пользователе (это в том случае если число будет разным для разных пользователей).

Comment: Да, спасибо, вопрос уже решил, прочитал фундаментальную документацию.